# Angular issue with Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I've a simple list made of `mat-card`. I would like to highlight the `mat-card` when dragging a file over and do something on the file drop, but I have two main issues:

- Sometimes, when dragging too fast, the status of the `mat-card` is not correctly updated. so in some cases I have multiple cards highligthed.
- The `e.preventDefault()` on drop event does nothing. The file is open in the browser, which is not the expected behaviour.

I tried so many things, even manually add/remove event listeners, but nothing worked. Hope someone will help :)

Here you can find a demo made in `stackblitz` so it can be easier to debug:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-d2uted

**Update:**
Using `Angular v5` and `Angular Material 2`

Comment: Not sure what version of material you're using, but CDK version 7.0.0-beta.0 introduces a drag and drop support - [docs available here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-drop.md).

Comment: @p4r1 using version 2.0.0-beta.12, and unfortunately I can't change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some poking around, the `dragover` event needs to be prevented as well as the `drop` event in order to stop the browser from opening the file. To fix the class being applied multiple times, I fixed this by using `ngClass` instead of the `ngIf` and it seems to work more consistently. Check out [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-rjaeg7) for a demo.

Comment: Great great great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, this is because of Angular lifecycle that isn't fast enough. Either you stop using Angular's context to update your elements, or you find another way of notifying the user that he is above the application.

For the second issue, add an host listener to the `window:dragover` event to prevent the default :

```
@HostListener('window:dragover', ['$event'])
windowDragOver(event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-zbczxb?file=app/card/card.component.ts)